# Error al usar JSON

Tags: json

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (app.js:138)
```

No he podido avanzar, necesito borrar un contacto de la base de datos pero me sale el error de arriba. Lo hago tal cual como dice la clase y me sale ese error.

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor? Muchas gracias.

este es el código de js.

```
const formularioContactos = document.querySelector('#contacto'),   //Nueva sintaxis de Javascript. Se coge el id de contacto que esta en editar.php
      listadoContactos = document.querySelector('#listado-contactos tbody');

eventListeners();  //Funcion que se usa para llamar una vez que se ejecute el codigo//

function eventListeners() {
   //cuando el formulario de editar o crear se ejecuta
   formularioContactos.addEventListener('submit', leerFormulario); //cuando alguien de click en añadir o en editar, se ejecutala funcion leer formulario. ES UNA FUNCION

   //listener para eliminar boton
   listadoContactos.addEventListener('click', eliminarContacto);
}

function leerFormulario(e){    //prevenir la accion por default es añadir una e detro del parentesis
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log('presionaste');  Revisa si sirve el boton
    //Leer los datos de los inputs
    const nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value,  //lee los datos del ID que estan en formulario. Para poder que funcione traigo el valor del input que se llama value. Compruebo si los valores tienen algo
          empresa = document.querySelector('#empresa').value,
          telefono = document.querySelector('#telefono').value,
          accion = document.querySelector('#accion').value; //Esta accion viene de la parte de formulario y con el boton añadir.
    //console.log(nombre); compruebo si los valores tienen algo
    if(nombre === '' || empresa === '' || telefono === ''){ 
        //2 parametros texto y clase
        mostrarNotificacion('Todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');   // Se crea el parametro y va a la parte de la function mostrarNotificacion con una clase 'error'  //Esta notificacion se muestra gracias a lo que se creo abajo NOTIFICACION PANTALLA                               //console.log('Los campos estan vacios'); //forma sencilla de validar para ver si hay algo en el formulario
    } else {
         //pasa la validacion y crear el llamado a AJAX   //console.log('Tienen algo');
         const infoContacto = new FormData();  //Forma para leer los datos de un formulario
         infoContacto.append('nombre', nombre); //se utiliza la funcion append y se pasa la llave 'nombre' y el valor seria la variable de nombre y viene de la parte de arriba.
         infoContacto.append('empresa', empresa);
         infoContacto.append('telefono', telefono);
         infoContacto.append('accion', accion); //me va a decir si es editar o crear

        //console.log(...infoContacto); //aparece que esta vacio

          if(accion === 'crear'){ //este crear sale del boton de añadir que esta en el hiiden
            //crearemos un nuevo contacto
            insertarBD(infoContacto);  //se crea una funcion que se llama insertarBD y va a tomar el form data
          } else {
              //editar contacto
          }
  }
}
//inserta en la base de datos via AJAX
function insertarBD(datos) {   //se ejecuta una funcion y toma como parametro unos datos puede ser INFOCONTACTO o solo datos
//llamado a AJAX

//crear el objeto
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//abrir la conexion
xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php', true);  //primero el tipo de peticion que es: POST.Se utiliza cuando insertas algo a la BD en un formulario y GET es para obtener algo que esta en el servidor

//pasar los datos
xhr.onload = function() {  //leer la respuesta
  if(this.status === 200) { //quiere decir que la conexion fue exitosa
     console.log(JSON.parse( xhr.responseText) ); //convierte el string a json los () para acceder a los valores individualmente
     //leemos la respuesta de PHP
     const respuesta = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText); //creo una variable con nombre respueta. En este caso se muestra un objeto. 

          //inserta un nuevo elemento a la tabla                                                                  //console.log(respuesta.empresa); //el .empresa.nombre.telefono porque lo que viene siendo JSON parse lo convierte a objeto de JS
           const nuevoContacto = document.createElement('tr');

           nuevoContacto.innerHTML =`            
               <td>${respuesta.datos.nombre}</td>
               <td>${respuesta.datos.empresa}</td>
               <td>${respuesta.datos.telefono}</td>
           `;       // los template strings son la nueva forma de cocatenar valores         

           //crear contenedor botones
           const contenedorAcciones = document.createElement('td');

           //crear el icono de editar
           const iconoEditar = document.createElement('i');
           iconoEditar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-pen-square');

           //crea el enlace para editar
           const btnEditar = document.createElement('a');
           btnEditar.appendChild(iconoEditar);
           btnEditar.href = `editar.php?id=${respuesta.datos.id_insertado}`;
           btnEditar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-editar');

        //agregarlo al padre
        contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnEditar);

        //crear el icono de eliminar
        const iconoEliminar = document.createElement('i');
        iconoEliminar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash-alt');

        //crear el boton de eliminar
        const btnEliminar = document.createElement('button');
        btnEliminar.appendChild(iconoEliminar);
        btnEliminar.setAttribute('data_id', respuesta.datos.id_insertado);
        btnEliminar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-borrar');

        //agregarlo al padre
        contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnEliminar);

        //agregarlo al tr
        nuevoContacto.appendChild(contenedorAcciones);

        //agregarlo con los contactos
        listadoContactos.appendChild(nuevoContacto);

        //resetear el formulario
        document.querySelector('form').reset();    //quiero que me retorne un formulario y metodo de js para restear el formulario
        //mostrar Notificacion

        mostrarNotificacion('Contacto Creado Correctamente', 'correcto'); //Primero toma el mensaje y despues la clase
    } 
}

//enviar los datos
xhr.send(datos);  //le paso los datos que quiero enviar. POST agregar nuevos datos a lo que ya existe
}

*****//eliminar el contacto*****
function eliminarContacto(e) {
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-borrar')) {  

     //tomar el id
     const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data_id');
     //console.log(id);
     //preguntar al usuario
     const respuesta = confirm('Estas seguro?');

     if(respuesta) {
         //llamado a AJAX
         //crear el obejto
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

         //abrir la conexion
        xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);

         //leer la respuesta
         xhr.onload = function() {
             if(this.status === 200) {
                 **const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);**

            console.log(resultado);
             }
         }
         //enviar la peticion
         xhr.send(); //cuando se envia por POST se agrega la variable
     }
   }
}

//Notificacion en pantalla
function mostrarNotificacion(mensaje, clase) { //Todos los campos son obligatorios pasa a ser un mensaje con la clase   //crear la funcion y se le pone mostrarNotificacion
    const notificacion = document.createElement('div'); //se crea una variable con nombre notificacion 
    notificacion.classList.add(clase, 'notificacion', 'sombra'); //creo una nueva clase llamado notificacion, le doy un nombre y genero un div, una clase y un contenido. Esto ayuda para que desaparezca ya que se creo en css. Es clase genera error o exito
    notificacion.textContent = mensaje;  //y ese mensaje pasa a ser parte del text content. Se reemplaza hubo un error    //se crea una notificacion conel texto

    //Formulario
    formularioContactos.insertBefore(notificacion, document.querySelector('form legend'));  //este formulario contiene el form. 1.Toma lo QUE  se va a insertar. 2. y DONDE se va a insertar. ENTONCES voy a insertar la notificacion y DESPUES en el lado que quiero. va antes de nombre, empresa, telefono

    //Ocultar y mostrar la notificacion
    setTimeout(() => {    //Es una funcion que va a esperar cierto tiempo en ejecutar un codigo
        notificacion.classList.add('visible');       //le va a agregar una clase visible. forma de javascript para escribir
    setTimeout(() => {
        notificacion.classList.remove('visible');  
         setTimeout(() => {
            notificacion.remove(); //hace que JS remueva la notificacion cuando ya no se usa
        }, 500);
    }, 3000); //3000 a partir de 3 segundos desaparece

    }, 100); //100 es una decima parte de un segundo
}
```

Comment: ¿Que esta devolviendote la llamada a la API? parece que el fallo viene de ahi.

Comment: Hola francisco, pues yo cambie todo por metodo GET y me funciono, pero ya despues iba a validar los campos y me marco error otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en que la cadena devuelto por la API no tiene formato correcto.

Puedes intentar convertiendo tu cadena a JSON:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  if(this.status === 200) {

     //Convertir cadena a JSON
     const myJson = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText);

     const respuesta = JSON.parse(myJson);

     console.log(respuesta);
  }
}
```